# PowerShell Regex Multilined

Tags: regex, powershell

working with Regex and have hit a brick wall.

```
$AddressEdit = Select-String "c:\utilities\AddressStaged.txt" -pattern "^(?!<img src)"  | Select Line | Out-File "c:\utilities\Address.txt"
```

Above returns some of the data I need. However, there is a line in the text file that always occurs right after this line that is returned that I also want to include in my output into a new document.

My Question: Is there a way for regex to say "Grab this line and also the line of data right below the one you have found from the pattern result"?

Comment: No, not RegEx, but Select-String will do that. Try running `get-help Select-String -detailed` and check out the `-Context` parameter.

Comment: It seems that you are attempting to parse html content. Use the HtmlAgility pack for that. It can be used from powershell quite easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use RegEx with multilinematching using -Raw param of `Get-Content`.

I give this answer for the technical feasibility, for the operational point of view, you should follow @TheMadTechnician or @David Brabant advices.

Here is an XML file (M.txt):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Machines xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Machine>
    <Nom>JPBHPP2.marceau.fr</Nom>
    <IP>192.168.2.61</IP>
    <Creation>2014-06-05T06:35:25.2318584+02:00</Creation>
    <Masque-IPv4>255.255.255.0</Masque-IPv4>
  </Machine>
  <Machine>
    <Nom>JPBASUSF2.marceau.fr</Nom>
    <IP>192.168.2.81</IP>
    <Creation>2014-06-05T06:35:20.7676768+02:00</Creation>
    <Masque-IPv4>255.255.255.0</Masque-IPv4>
  </Machine>
</Machines>
```

Now load the file as  a single string:

```
$a = Get-Content D:\temp\M1.xml -Raw
```

Then try this RegEx :

```
$reg = [regex]'(?sm)  (<Nom>.*?</Nom>\r\n.*?\r\n)'
```

It gives :

```
$reg.Matches($a).count # gives 2
$reg.Matches($a).Groups[0].value
# gives 
#  <Nom>JPBHPP2.marceau.fr</Nom>
#    <IP>192.168.2.61</IP>
```

---

Updated to answer to your question : is it possible to start with a Regex and end with a regex and gather everything between? Here is a way to take everything between `<Nom>` and `</IP>`.

```
$reg = [regex]'(?sm)(<Nom>.*?</IP>)'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and it was what I was looking for but with a slight alteration.

for example: You're returning 
#  <Nom>JPBHPP2.marceau.fr</Nom>
#    <IP>192.168.2.61</IP>

which is fine but is it possible to start with a Regex and end with a regex and gather everything between?
I can understand how it works with a clear static string though so thank you.